# nano and echo behave different at inotify

Tags: go, echo, inotify, nano

I did a small test sw in go and inotify.
It detects file modifications.

If I do the textfile modification with nano, I get two modification detections,
If I do it wit echo I get only one modification detection.
I think this is caused by nano editor.

echo 1 >> /sw/config.yml

nano /sw/config.yml

Does anybody has a explanation ?

Code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify"
)

func inotwatcher(watcher *fsnotify.Watcher) {

    for {
        select {
        case event := <-watcher.Events:
            // monitor only for write events
            if event.Op&fsnotify.Write == fsnotify.Write {
                fmt.Println("Modified file:", event.Name)
            }
        case err := <-watcher.Errors:
            log.Println("Error:", err)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    // setup inotify watcher
    watcher, _ := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    defer watcher.Close()
    //done := make(chan bool)

    go inotwatcher(watcher)
    watcher.Add("/busa/config.yml")
    for {
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't post links to code or other resources. Include the code in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Nano is a text editor and will handle the changes differently than output redirection in a shell, assuming that's what you mean by editing with echo, `echo` is a shell command and not even doing the file modification. Some editors will replace the file entirely on write, you just need to deal with whatever possible modifications you need to detect.